# Getting segmentation fault or code haults

Tags: c++

When I run my code (it is written in root which is c++ based programming language) then either it gives me segmentation fault or it stucks at a point but I could not figure out why it happens. Below is the details of my code.

```
DataArray* g[MaxNumbersOfDetDir];
for(Int_t i=0; i<MaxNumbersOfDetDir; i++)
     {
     if (testCout)cout<<"test"<<endl;
     g[i] = new DataArray((const int)PossibleHits[i]);
     if (testCout)cout<<"Possible hits = "<<PossibleHits[i]<<"\t g[i] = "<<g[i]<<endl;
     }
```

This DataArray Class is defined as

```
//Constructor with number of elements to allocate
DataArray::DataArray(const int maxNumOfChannels) 
  : TObject(), nallocated(0), nch(0), ch(0)
{ 
if (COUT)cout<<"in Dataarray cpp 11"<<endl;
  if (maxNumOfChannels > 0)  
    {   
if (COUT)cout<<"in Dataarray cpp 22 = "<<maxNumOfChannels<<endl;
      ch = new chtype[maxNumOfChannels];
if (COUT)cout<<"in Dataarray cpp 22 ch = "<<ch<<endl;
      nallocated = maxNumOfChannels;
if (COUT){      std::cout << "New object with " << nallocated 
        << " elements. "<<ch<<"\t Object at " 
        << (this) << std::endl; }
    };  
}
```

So, My codes stops on the line

```
 ch = new chtype[maxNumOfChannels];
```

Is the information given is sufficient or should I give more information?

Comment: what value for maxNumOfChannels at runtime?

Comment: Give the output info (the one that COUT shows just after hanging). Also, the number of `MaxNumbersOfDetDir`.

Comment: MaxNumberOfDetDir = 25 

And it just gives the output before the line ch = new chtype[maxNumOfChannels]; but not after that.

Comment: maxNumOfChannels = 256

Comment: What is `chtype`? If that's a class, there might be something wrong in its constructor.

Comment: And ch is =>  chtype *ch;

Comment: Please, provide a ["Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  You need to give a program that when pasted into a file and checked by others generates a precise failure.  If you cannot do that then it indicates the cause of the problem is in code other than what's in your example--in which case, no one can be expected to be able to reproduce it.  But pasting a large body of code is not acceptable, because it's your job to pare it down to a small reproducible case.